# Regex expression to validate phone number in a specific sequence

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to validate a phone number in my code . The validation is that number is invalid if it is in any of the following sequences -

```
111-111-1111
333-333-3333
444-444-4444
123-123-1234
123-456-7890
```

Any number (in this sequence xxx-xxx-xxxx) other than the above ones are valid, and should not be caught in validation I have come up with this regex to validate the first three sequence

```
^([0-9])\1{2}\1{3}\1{4}$
```

Any lead will be great help.

Comment: You'll probably want to use Integer.parse and other stuff for the last 2 - regex isn't adequate for stuff like sequences

Comment: mindSet - any update?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to maintain a `List` of restricted series/number and then check a phone number if it belongs to the `List`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> restrictedList = List.of("111-111-1111", "333-333-3333", "444-444-4444", "123-123-1234",
                "123-456-7890");
        String[] testNumbers = { "444-444-4544", "444-444-4444", "121-111-1111", "333-343-3333", "123-123-1234",
                "123-456-7890", "123-465-7890", "213-123-1234", "1234567890", "111-111-1111", "a1b2c3d4e5",
                "333-333-3333", "223-334-4445", "2134-12-4321", "100-200-3000", "011-243-7234" };
        for (String number : testNumbers) {
            if (number.matches("[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}") && !restrictedList.contains(number)) {
                System.out.println(number + " is valid.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
444-444-4544 is valid.
444-444-4444 is invalid.
121-111-1111 is valid.
333-343-3333 is valid.
123-123-1234 is invalid.
123-456-7890 is invalid.
123-465-7890 is valid.
213-123-1234 is valid.
1234567890 is invalid.
111-111-1111 is invalid.
a1b2c3d4e5 is invalid.
333-333-3333 is invalid.
223-334-4445 is valid.
2134-12-4321 is invalid.
100-200-3000 is valid.
011-243-7234 is invalid.
```

**Note:** I've used `[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}` as the format of a phone number assuming that the first digit can not be `0`.